# Sorting an array based on value of child object

Tags: php

What's the most efficient way to sort this array based on the 'offset' value?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day] => 12
            [month] => 2
            [year] => 2013
            [start] => 12:30pm
            [end] => 3:00pm
            [timestamp] => 2013-02-12 15:00:00
            [id] => 2147483647
            [offset] => -6595200
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day] => 4
            [month] => 5
            [year] => 2013
            [start] => 4:00pm
            [end] => 5:00pm
            [timestamp] => 2013-05-04 17:00:00
            [id] => 538154873
            [offset] => 406800
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day] => 12
            [month] => 5
            [year] => 2013
            [start] => 7:00am
            [end] => 10:30am
            [timestamp] => 2013-05-12 10:30:00
            [id] => 1738975402
            [offset] => 1074600
        )
```

I'd like to return the item from the array with the smallest 'offset' value.

Is `usort()` a good option? How does that work when arrays and objects are mixed?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you care of efficiency in case of having 3 objects? Is the question about basic function usage or about solving performance issue?

Comment: Question is mostly about basic function usage, but the array could grow to be 100+ items and wanted to be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as what you are sorting is an array, it's fine.  You can do

```
usort ($array , function($a, $b) { 
   if ($a->offset == $b->offset) {
     return 0;
   }
   return ($a->offset < $b->offset) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks dave!